# How to get user Insert statistics in MySQL

Tags: mysql, statistics, multi-master

I'm trying to get statistics on the write load on my MySQL servers.
Something like what `show global status like "Com_%";` gives me.

but, here comes the catch - we're using Master-Master replication.
The "Com" statistics MySQL collects include the updates/inserts from the Replication.
so I get the same "Com_update" value on all hosts in the cluster.

I need the writes load on the current machine only.
I want to see how many insert commands get to each server.
(I understand that the total load of writes will obviously be the same but want to monitor which servers are accessed by the application servers for writes)

We use MySQL 5.6 & 5.7.

Thanks in advance,
 - Jony

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

*Caveat:  This Answer was written before the Edit of the Question.  So it does not really address the final Question.*

Turn on `log_slow_slave_statements`.  That way, you can catch slow replicated queries in the slowlog (if using SBR).

`Com_*` values need to be divided by `Uptime` to get something more useful.  Even so, they are not very useful.  An `UPDATE` that changes all rows in a million-row table will count as only one `Com_update`.

If you are using InnoDB, there are other `STATUS` values relating to "writes" and "pages" that come closer to measuring IOPs, which is what your hardware (or cloud provider) will have a limit on.

If your goal is to figure out what to do about "high load", then I strongly recommend setting `long_query_time = 1`, turning on the slowlog, waiting a day, and using `pt-query-digest` to find the worst few queries.  Then let us help you speed them up.

If you would like further analysis of the `STATUS`, please provide RAM size, `SHOW VARIABLES;` and `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;`

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I'm not looking for the load from replication but rather want to monitor direct commands.
for example:
200 inserts on DB1.  
300 inserts on DB2.  

(the total 500 which shows in Com* is the total load which is good but not what I need for now...)